# Chrome mobile emulation. Window size is different via Selenium and Devtools

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, emulation, mobile-chrome

Need to test web site responsibility.
Code example taken from [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation) (in the bottom of page)
Faced, that selenium opens chrome window in different size/resolution, than i expect. Looks like that pixelRatio is not accepted or accepted incorrectly.
Also, faced, that in devtools, devices size from default device list is already divided on pixelRatio. e.g. Iphone 6 has 750 x 1334 and pixelRatio 2.0, but in devtools it is 375 x 667 which perfectly fits ***original resolution*** divided on ***pixelRatio***. But if I manually add custom device 750 x 1334 with pixelRatio 2.0, it still shows me 750 x 1334
In [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/module.json) Iphone 6 already defined with 'divided' size and pixelRatio 2.0

```
"title": "Apple iPhone 6",
            "screen": {
                "horizontal": {
                    "width": 667,
                    "height": 375
                },
                "device-pixel-ratio": 2,
                "vertical": {
                    "width": 375,
                    "height": 667
                }
```

Here is sample of my enum for mobile devices.

```
public enum ChromeMobileDevice {
   IPHONE_8(1334, 750, 2.0, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"),
   IPHONE_XS_MAX(2688, 1242, 3.0, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/69.0.3497.105 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1"),
   GALAXY_S8(2960, 1440, 4.0, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G892A Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/60.0.3112.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"),
   IPAD_MINI(2048, 1536, 2.0, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"),
   GALAXY_TAB_10_1(1920, 1200, 1.0, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SM-T580) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36");

   private int height;
   private int width;
   private double pixelRatio;
   private String userAgent;
   private boolean touch = false;

   private ChromeMobileDevice(int height, int width, double pixelRatio, String userAgent) {
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
      this.pixelRatio = pixelRatio;
      this.userAgent = userAgent;
   }

   public static ChromeMobileDevice getByName(final String chromeMobileDeviceName) {
      return Stream.of(ChromeMobileDevice.values()).filter(b -> b.name().equalsIgnoreCase(chromeMobileDeviceName)).findAny()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unsupported chrome emulator name: %s", chromeMobileDeviceName)));
   }

   public HashMap<String, Object> getPortraitDeviceMetrics() {
      return Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(
            "height", height,
            "width", width,
            "pixelRatio", pixelRatio,
            "touch", touch));
   }

   public HashMap<String, Object> getLandscapeDeviceMetrics() {
      return Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(
            "width", height,
            "height", width,
            "pixelRatio", pixelRatio,
            "touch", touch));
   }
}
```

**UPD**
Sample of chromedriver creation

```
ChromeOptions capabilities = new ChromeOptions();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", "disable-extensions");
capabilities.setCapability(SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
capabilities.addArguments("--hide-scrollbars");
capabilities.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
capabilities.addArguments("--start-maximized");
capabilities.addArguments("--disable-infobars");

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
ChromeMobileDevice chromeMobileDevice = ChromeMobileDevice.getByName(chromeMobileEmulation.get());
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", chromeMobileDevice.getUserAgent());
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", chromeMobileDevice.getPortraitDeviceMetrics());

capabilities.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities );
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates an instance of ChromeDriver?

Comment: @GregBurghardt done, but nothing special there. resolution is changed, problem is that it's not scaled. if in chromedriver source resoulution is already divided on pixelRatio, why do we need to add it into a code. if it's needed for css scaling, why not to use original size and hide divide process. that cofusing me, and i assume bug in my code or devtools